# Unable to manage existing recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

my captcha keys are working, however, unable to add new domains or manage existing keys.
when accessing the site i receive an error "You don't have any sites registered to use the reCAPTCHA API"
has anyone faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it wasn't clear that you must keep your own email address in order to view all your keys. When we generated these keys, we removed our personal accounts and used a distribution group so that the distribution group would receive notifications. Make sure you keep your own email address as well.